# GROUP BY for specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a sql server result which groups by person. And SUMS's their daily figure and monthly figure.

```
    Person  Team    Daily Figure    Month To Date
    Tony    Team 1          53              635
    Dan     Team 2         47               172
    Tom     Team 3         17               232
    Simon   Team 2          16              655
    Ben     Team 3         17               232
    Fred    Team 2          16              655
```

How do i group these results just by team 2? For example i still want the others individual results to show but i want just team 2 to be grouped together.

Example result

```
   Person   Team    Daily Figure    Month To Date
    Tony    Team 1          53              635
    Tom     Team 3         17               232
    Ben     Team 3         17               232
   Team 2   Team 2         79              1482
```

Thanks
UPDATE:

```
    SELECT 

     Person = case when Team = 'Team 2' 
     then 'Team 2' else Person  END,
     Team,
     SUM(ISNULL(Figure,0)) AS 'Daily Figure',
     SUM(Month To Date) AS 'Month To Date'
```

This is my select and it errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression for `Person` both in the `select` and the `group by`:

```
select 
    case when Team = 'Team 2' then 'Team 2' else Person end as Person
  , Team
  , sum([Daily Figure]) as [Daily Figure]
  , sum([Month To Date]) as [Month To Date]
from t
group by
    case when Team = 'Team 2' then 'Team 2' else Person end
  , Team
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XHQ24032

returns:

```
+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+
| Person | Team   | Daily Figure | Month To Date |
+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+
| Tony   | Team 1 |           53 |           635 |
| Team 2 | Team 2 |           79 |          1482 |
| Ben    | Team 3 |           17 |           232 |
| Tom    | Team 3 |           17 |           232 |
+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

---

If you want to use [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to avoid having to repeat the `case` expression:

```
select 
    x.Person
  , t.Team
  , sum(t.[Daily Figure]) as [Daily Figure]
  , sum(t.[Month To Date]) as [Month To Date]
from t
  cross apply (
    select case when t.Team = 'Team 2' then 'Team 2' else t.Person end as Person
    ) as x 
group by
    x.Person
  , t.Team
```

Or with [**`cross apply(values())`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select 
    x.Person
  , t.Team
  , sum(t.[Daily Figure]) as [Daily Figure]
  , sum(t.[Month To Date]) as [Month To Date]
from t
  cross apply (values 
   (case when t.Team = 'Team 2' then 'Team 2' else t.Person end)
    ) as x (Person)
group by
    x.Person
  , t.Team
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY will make that query a bit nicer

Comment: i tried  Person= case when Team LIKE 'Team 2' then ''Team 2"  else Person  END, but this just errors in both the select and group by

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Don't use double quotes for strings. Why use `like 'Team 2'` when your sample data indicates `Team` is an integer, and you would just use `Team = 2` or if it was a character type, then `Team = '2'`?

Comment: it doesnt work with equals either - "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I've updated my demo and code to use your updated question sample data and everything works using `Team = 'Team 2'`. If you are using the first solution with two `case` expressions, make sure you are not including the alias `Person =` in the `group by`, only use the expression in the `group by`.

Comment: ive added the select code to my question and it errors

Comment: this is also selecting from a view, i dont know if that effects anything?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Based on your latest update, your `SUM(Month To Date) AS 'Month To Date'` should be `SUM([Month To Date]) AS [Month To Date]`. Do not use string literals as column aliases, use square brackets around alias names that do not conform to the rules for [Database Identifiers - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers). e.g. `

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I have updated my answer to use the `expr as [alias]` style that you seem to prefer.

Comment: @SqlZim - finally got this working using the cross apply method. Thanks so much for your help